# Excel table formulas to return blank

Tags: excel, formula

I have a table in excel with 2 columns, the E column is the running total the D column is the input value so normally it would be = E15+D16 however, i want the E column to return a blank if nothing is entered in the D column- what formula do I need?

```
1   Nov-23  Nov-30  1,230   1,230
2   Dec-01  Dec-07  130     1,360
3   Dec-08  Dec-14  416     1,776
4   Dec-15  Dec-21  124     1,900
5   Dec-22  Dec-28  102     2,002
6   Dec-29  Jan-04  83      2,085
7   Jan-05  Jan-11  95      2,180
8   Jan-12  Jan-18  88      2,268
9   Jan-19  Jan-25  102     2,370
10  Jan-26  Feb-01  130     2,500
11  Feb-02  Feb-08  311     2,811
12  Feb-09  Feb-15      
13              
14              
15              
16              
17              
18              
19              
20              
21              
22
```

Answer (score 3):

```
=if(D16="","",E15+D16)
```

You dont even need the ISBLANK, just use empty quotes.

Answer (score 0):

`ISBLANK` is what you're looking for.

In E16 `=IF(ISBLANK(D16), "", E15+D16)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `If` and `IsBlank` in conjunction.

Do a check to see if the cell is blank, then depending on the result do the sum or the return blank.  I don't have excel in front of me atm, but it should go something like this:

> =if(ISBLANK(D16), "", E15+D16)

You can drag this down starting from the *second* cell in the column where this running total lives.  The first one is obviously just the value from the adjacent cell.

Comment: @user1817456 If you're happy with the solution proposed - please accept the answer by ticking it, this will mark the question solved.